# How to upload file in angularjs using wcf service?

Tags: angularjs, wcf

I stuck in my app, I want to upload file using angular js with wcf service, I am using wcf service to manipulate into database. 
I have create one directive for file upload.

```
    myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;
                element.bind('change', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and service to call Post method.

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        debugger;
        $http.post('http://localhost:50202/WcfService/Service1.svc/fileUpload', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
    }
}]);
```

so issue is that when file convert into the byte wcf service say that size is too large. 
so can any one help me, how can I fragment file in to chunks and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the maximum message length in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will set the maximum message length to 400 MB (parameter is in kB).